Accessing QGIS Logs Programmatically in Plugin
I'm developing a QGIS plugin and I would like to access the QGIS log messages (the ones displayed in the Log Messages Panel) directly from my plugin code. This would help me with debugging and provide better error handling for users.
Specifically, I'm looking for:

A way to programmatically fetch the logs, including errors and warnings, generated by QGIS and other plugins.
If there is an existing API or class in the QGIS Python API that provides access to these logs.

I've searched through the QGIS Python documentation but couldn't find a clear method for this.
Does anyone know if it's possible, and if so, how I can achieve it?
